# InAppSettingsKit and Storyboard: how to put a back button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I'm using the ARC version of the InAppSettingsKit framework (https://github.com/tibr/InAppSettingsKit) to put the settings bundle into my application with Storyboard. I have managed to get the settings work but it shows the settings and I can't go back to the menus of my app.

[image: The navigationcontroller that i want]

[image: what it shows, it is a TableViewController]

Any Suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone else

I used the main branch with storyboards and the -fno-objc-arc flag but it should be the same solution

I am not sure how you got the back button in your picture above because my button shows as done.

I created a subclass called

```
@interface SettingsViewController : IASKAppSettingsViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate>
```

I linked the storyboard to use this class instead of the IASKAppSettingsViewController I added the ShowDoneButton = YES

```
@implementation SettingsViewController
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
 {
 self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
 if (self) {
     self.delegate = self;
     self.showDoneButton = YES;
 }
 return self;
}
```

My setup is storyboards with
a modal segue. 
a settings button on my main view which links to a navigation controller and a grouped table view